# Session not persisting on shared hosting - Laravel 4.2.17

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, session-cookies

I have a problem with the sessions on the shared hosting.

I developed an app on a local server (XAMPP) and it works great (sessions, auth etc). The problems have appeared when I moved the app on a shared hosting.

I realized that the sessions are not persisting from a page to another or from AJAX files to another page and the Authentication does not work either .

The only session that persists is the _token which has a different value after every refresh of the page.
I have the following configuration in the session.php file:

```
 'driver' => 'database', 
 'lifetime' => 120, 
 'expire_on_close' => false, 
 'lottery' => array(2, 100), 
 'path' => '/', 
 'domain' => null
```

First, I used file driver and I had the same problem, and now I used the database.

Both file and database work on the local server but on the shared hosting they do not.

I tried all the solutions found on the forum but still I have the same problem.

I think the problem is at the session domain setting because when I change the value from null to other string on my local server, I have the same problem that I have encountered online.

Can you help me, please!

Thanks, Mirel

Comment: What does your session table look like? Did you create a migration for it?

Comment: My migration is `Schema::create('sessions', function($table)
{
    $table->string('id')->unique();
    $table->text('payload');
    $table->integer('last_activity');
});`

Comment: I noticed that my **_token** session changes every time I refresh the page. And I think that is my problem. Every time I reload the page a new row is inserted in my session table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem. In my case the error because I have added a php closed tag `?>` in the end of the included files. So removing  this tag will bring the application back to normal behavior.